# If $(x - 2)$ is a factor of $x^3 + ax^2 -6x -4$, then find $a$.

Tags: polynomials

If $(x - 2)$ is a factor of $x^3 + ax^2 - 6x - 4$, then find $a$. This is regarding polynomials. The answer is $a = 2$. Could someone please provide the working out and help me out on this please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If $x-2$ is a factor of the polynomial, it means that when you plug $x=2$ into the polynomial, you get $0$. Do you see how this helps you?

Answer (score 1):

Factorize the polynomial:

$x^3+ax^2-6x-4=(x-2)(x^2+(a+2)x+2(a-1))+4a-8$

Therefore $x^3+ax^2-6x-4 \pmod {x-2} \equiv 4a-8$

Because $x-2$ is the factor of $x^3+ax^2-6x-4$, then $4a-8=0$.

$\therefore a=2$

Comment: How do you type x to the power of 3 so it looks the way you did it.

Comment: @Orbit enclose math in dollar signs.  For example, `$x^3$` makes $x^3$.

Comment: Thank you so much for that

Answer (score 0):

So the expression should be $0$ when you put $x=2$. Thus, $8+4a-12-4=0$. So $a=2$

Comment: You should not give out answers like this. Especially when the OP has not provided work.

Comment: Why does it matter. I just want an answer.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Point noted.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that if $(x - a)$ is a factor of a polynomial $f(x)$, then $f(a) = 0$.

Since $(x - 2)$ is a factor of $x^3 + ax^2 - 6x - 4$, the unfactored polynomial (substituted with $x = 2$) must be $0$.  Therefore...

$$\begin{aligned}
(2)^3 + a(2)^2 - 6(2) - 4 &= 0\\
8 + 4a - 12 - 4 &= 0\\
4a - 8 &= 0\\
4a &= 8\\
a &= 2
\end{aligned}$$